# Does C++ treat char pointers as c style strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, c-strings

Does C++ treat char pointers as c-style strings?

```cpp
int main(int argc,char* argv[])
{
    if (argv[1] == "-d")
    {

    }
}
```

argv[1] contains a char pointer, how is the statement `argv[1] == "-d"` not causing the compiler to throw an error because `"d"` is a string whereas `argv[1]` is a pointer to a char value

Comment: Long story short, you need to use `strcmp`.

Comment: In the expression `argv[1] == "-d"`, the compiler converts `"-d"` to a pointer (equal to the address of the `'-'` in the string `"-d"`) and evaluates if `argv[1]` is equal to that pointer (which will generally test `false`).    If you want to treat `argv[1]` as a string (array of `char` terminated with as nul) and compare the contents of that string with the contents of the string literal, then do `std::strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)`.   Or, possibly better depending on your use case, create `std::string` objects from `argv[1]` and `"-d"` and compare those `std::string`s using the `==` operator.

Comment: What you said is true, but then how does the following code compile and produces the correct output
`int main()
{
    char* ptr[1];
    char c[] = "Hello";
    ptr[0] = c;
    std::string d = ptr[0];
    std::cout << d;
}`

how is a pointer being assigned to a string

Comment: You need to understand that pointers and arrays (and strings, which are technically an array with particular characteristics) are different things.   They can be treated - in some circumstances but not others - AS IF they are the same thing.   To understand why your last example works, but the example in your question doesn't, you need to understand when pointers and arrays can be treated AS IF they are the same thing, and when they cannot.    A full explanation of that is a bit much to do in this format.

Comment: @SwarajSonavane I get the impression that your understanding of what constitutes a "string" is flawed, which has led you to these questions. Perhaps one part of this: `"-d"` is a string literal, which is merely a special case of C-style strings; there are C-style strings that are not string literals.

Comment: @peter ok, thank you for your answer . Do you know a source  I can refer to, to understand under what circumstances char pointers  and strings can be treated the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> because `"d"` is a string whereas `argv[1]` is a pointer to a `char` value

That's where you're *kind of* wrong friend.

`argv[1]` is in this case a `char*` like you said.

`"-d"` is a `const char[3]` (`-d` plus the null terminator), this array can decay to a pointer which means `==` compiles.

As pointed out in the comments though, this will probably not do what you expect it to do. This will do a pointer comparison and not a comparison of the actual strings. You'll need to use `strcmp` for that.

Comment: But don't forget, *works* here only means it *compiles*. It will not do what you might expect it to do.

Comment: @SwarajSonavane Yes, and yes they will be (excluding black magic).